# Subtracting multiple values from same number

Tags: vba

How to subtract multiple values from the same number?

For example:

A = 1000

x = 200

y = 300

z = 400

In iteration 1: A - x = 800

In iteration 2: A - y = 500

In iteration 3: A - Z = 100

Can we assign a temporary variable to solve this problem? Also, I am looking to subtract all these values in a single cell that means the value should keep on changing in the single cell as follows A1: 800, A1: 500, A1: 100

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me how the value is supposed to be changing? Can you demonstrate with an example what you mean?

Comment: For example: I have $1000 to spend with me. First time I go and buy an ice-cream that costs me $100. That means I have $900 to spend now. Second time I go and buy some food for $400. That means I am left with $500. Every time I purchase something it should automatically change how much money is left with me. I hope it helps..

Comment: but what kind of solution are you looking for? you tagged your question VBA but provided no code? Where does 1000 come from? where do other variables come from? Where do you want to show the result? etc. Please provide us with more info otherwise your question is very unclear and may be receiving some close votes soon

Comment: Let's say cell(1,1) contains a random number 1000. Cell(2,1) can contain any value say 200. When I enter my first value in Cell(2,1) it changes values of cell(1,1) to 800. Similarly when I enter my second value in cell (2,1) say 300, it should change value in cell (1,1) to 500.

Comment: Surprising you have received two answers based on the quality of this question.

Comment: @brettdj the solution to this sounds as simple as `A1 = 1000 - B1 - C1 - D1` etc assuming the B1 = x, C1 = y, D1 = z

Comment: @brettdj: OP is probably a beginner, so I thought I'd give them the benefit of the doubt and get them started with a basic answer they can build upon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started on your programming adventure:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim a As Double
Dim values As Variant
a = 1000
values = Array(200, 300, 400)
For i = LBound(values) To UBound(values)
    a = a - values(i)
    Range("A1") = a
    MsgBox "Cell A1 now contains: " & Range("A1").Value
Next i
```

Comment: Its a good starting point. I will play with it first.

Comment: My values are constantly changing in a cell. For example: Values = shtSheet1. Cells (1,2) instead of defined array. First time it can be 200 and then 300 and so on. What to do in this case?

Comment: One question per question please... I suggest you ask a new question, showing clearly: input, desired output, what you have tried to achieve this desired output, and what specific problem you are encountering.

Comment: + 1 Good one. But in this case (since there is a pattern), I would not use an array. I would go in for something like `For i = 200 To 400 Step 100` :P

Comment: Thanks Jean.. I modified the code and it worked for me!